Why isn't the loop running even once
Given a positive integer that fits in a 32-bit signed integer, find if it can be expressed as A^P where P > 1 and A > 0.
A and P both should be integers.
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int A = 4;

    if (A == 1)
        cout << 1;
    else if (A < 4)
        cout << 0;
    int N;
    for (int P = 2; 2 <= pow(A + 1, 1 / P); P++) {
        N = pow(A, 1 / P);
        if (pow(N, P) == A)
            cout << 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


what is the expected, what is actual output? What makes you come to the conclusion that the loop is not executed? DId you use a debugger?

pow is not for integers. It returns a floating point value and comparing that via == to the expected value should not be expected to yield true

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

When P > 1, pow(A + 1, 1 / P) is pow(A + 1, 0), which is 1.

I guess it should be pow(A+1, 1.0/P), 1/P is integer division and so it is equal to zero for P > 1.

Or you can cast P to double.

The maximum value of P is base-2 log of A. That's one thing to fix. The second issue is that you should replace pow with ipow. And then the only issue left is integer overflow.

Somehow I have the feeling you are trying to use Python logic in C++

I am almost certain that if you do the maths first, then there is no need for brute forcing a loop to try all exponents

Near-duplicate of Why does dividing two int not yield the right value when assigned to double?

Why such stupid logic 2 <= pow(A + 1, 1 / P) and not pow(A + 1, 1 / P) >= 2?

@i486 they are exactly the same, no?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Same to compile, when reading they are a little different, no?

P is an int, so 1/P is computed as an int, with rounding toward zero.   Before the first iteration, P is 2, so 1/P is zero, and pow(A + 1, 1/P) gives 1, which is always less than 2.  This means your loop condition is false before the first loop iteration, and the loop body is never executed./

You are falling foul of integer division. 1 / P divides an int by an int, which has an int result. As P is greater than 1, the result is always 0, so your test is always false.
If at least one of the operands to / is a double, the other will be promoted to double and you will get a fractional result.
int main() {
    int A = 4;

    if (A == 1)
        cout << 1;
    else if (A < 4)
        cout << 0;
    int N;
    for (int P = 2; 2 <= pow(A + 1, 1.0 / P); P++) {
        N = pow(A, 1.0 / P);
        if (pow(N, P) == A)
            cout << 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


The primary issue with your loop not executing even once lies in the loop condition and the expression used within it. Specifically, the calculation of pow(A + 1, 1 / P) isn't doing what you might expect due to issues related to integer division and floating-point precision.
In C++, when both operands of the division operator / are integers, the division performed is integer division, which discards any remainder and returns an integer result. Thus, 1 / P will be 0 when P = 2, making pow(A + 1, 1 / P) evaluate to pow(A + 1, 0), which is always 1 regardless of the value of A. This causes the condition 2 <= pow(A + 1, 1 / P) to be false when A >= 3, so the loop doesn't run.
To fix this immediate issue, without changing the loop condition entirely, you can change both occurrences of 1 / P to 1.0 / P to force floating-point division, and the loop should work as you expect.
Try on godbolt.org
